# Speed does not improve with python extension with pyo3

Tags: python, rust

### My Environment

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Rust 1.36.0 (nightly)
- Python 3.7.3

### Problem

I want to write a python extension with Rust. I used PyO3 as follows,

```rust
use pyo3::prelude::*;


#[pymodule(example)]
fn rust2py(py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
     #[pyfn(m, "fib")]
     fn fib(_py: Python, n:i64) -> PyResult<i64> {
         let out = fib_rust(n);
         Ok(out)
     }

     Ok(())
}


fn fib_rust(n: i64) -> i64 {
      if n == 1 || n == 2 {
          return 1
      }

      fib_rust(n - 1) + fib_rust(n - 2)
}
```

I compared the speed of calculating Fibonacci sequence between extension with rust and pure python. I built this program as

```sh
cargo build --release
```

and copied `.so` file in current directory. I measured the elapsed time with time library in python, but that was almost same between extension and pure python.

What is wrong in this program.

Comment: This just means python is good at executing simple code.

Comment: Oh, I understood. if I introduced for loop, the rust extension was speedy, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

As SOFe said, in simple code, the difference between pure python and rust extension is ignoble. When I put for loop in my code, the performance was high in extension with rust.